# angular js sorting and pagination

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, pagination

Need to fix the gap i.e. `5` between pagination for now its is showing complete length. for example if we have `$scope.itemsPerPage = 5`and total length of object is `20`, then we get pagination `4`. But if `$scope.itemsPerPage = 2` and total length of object is `20`, then we get pagination `10`.

But I have to keep this constant as `5`

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var sortingOrder = 'name';
        </script>

        <div ng-controller="ctrlRead">
            <!--<div ng-include="'searchbox.html'"></div>-->
            <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="id">Id&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('id')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="name">Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('name')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="description">Description&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('description')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="field3">Field 3&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field3')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="field4">Field 4&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field4')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="field5">Field 5&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field5')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <div class="pagination pull-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                                <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length)"
                                ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
                                ng-click="setPage()">
                                <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                                <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage]| orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
                        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.field4}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.field5}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

My app.js file
function ctrlRead($scope, $filter) {
    // init
    $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.filteredItems = [];
    $scope.groupedItems = [];
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 2;
    $scope.pagedItems = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.items = [
        {"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
        {"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}, 
        {"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"}, 
        {"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"}, 
        {"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"}, 
        {"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"}, 
        {"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"}, 
        {"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"}, 
        {"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"}, 
        {"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"}, 
        {"id":"11","name":"name 11","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"}, 
        {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"}, 
        {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"}, 
        {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"}, 
        {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"}, 
        {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"}, 
        {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"}, 
        {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"}, 
        {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"}, 
        {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
    ];

    var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
        if (!needle) {
            return true;
        }
        return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    };

    // init the filtered items
    $scope.search = function () {
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
            for(var attr in item) {
                if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        // take care of the sorting order
        if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
            $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
        }
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        // now group by pages
        $scope.groupToPages();
    };

    // calculate page in place
    $scope.groupToPages = function () {
        $scope.pagedItems = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
            if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ $scope.filteredItems[i] ];
            } else {
                $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.range = function (start, end) {
        var ret = [];
        if (!end) {
            end = start;
            start = 0;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
            $scope.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    $scope.setPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = this.n;
    };

    // functions have been describe process the data for display
    $scope.search();

    // change sorting order
    $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {
        if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

        $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

        // icon setup
        $('th i').each(function(){
            // icon reset
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
        });
        if ($scope.reverse)
            $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
        else
            $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    };
};
ctrlRead.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];
```

Comment: it's preferably to provide working code snippets on JSFiddle or other similar resources. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $scope.getRange = function() {
        return $scope.range( $scope.pagedItems.length  > 5  ? 5 : $scope.pagedItems.length);
    }
```

```html
<ul>
                            <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                                <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-repeat="n in getRange()"
                                ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
                                ng-click="setPage()">
                                <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                                <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: add above method on your js file, and update template <li ng-repeat="n in getRange()", it will helpfull

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but it is keeping fix the pagination to five  but values r not changing after 5